# XAMPP mySQL console errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

So I've been using XAMPP for learning mySQL on my Mac. But as I typed simple instructions such as grant or revoke in the console of phpMyAdmin and hit execute, it returns numerous errors. I've also uninstalled/reinstalled it several times both on my Mac and Windows machine (windows 10). Here's a link to screenshot of the error. Keep in mind, there are like a hundred of those "notes" in blue boxes up there, all from places like "library" like the one in the picture. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: switched to MAMP on mac and it worked out fine for me.

Comment: Can you post the errors which are supposed to be listed at the bottom of the window?

Comment: it's not the bottom (that's where syntax errors are posted I think) it's in the middle, the blue boxes (not the yellow boxes my mistake) "Notice in ..." that stuff. It's more like a runtime error of some sort.